# replicate url permalink after migrating to wordpress

Tags: permalinks, urls

im trying to map WordPress URL slug/permalink from the previous slug/permalink cms (I'm migrating from non Wordpress into Wordpress)

Old cms has post slug/permalink structure as follow

post url

`domain/index.php/article/view/123`

category URL

`domain/index.php/category`

on Wordpress setting , I've setup permalinks as follow

[image]

post URL seems I don't have any issue to replicate, but I have a problem with category, my category URL was transformed into

`https://comain/article/view/index.php/uncategorized`

where it was supposed to

`https://comain/index.php/uncategorized`

how do I map my category URL accordingly? is there any plugin who able to control how my category URL slug/permalink?

thank you

Comment: Why do you want to show `index.php` in each of your URL's? Why not make a simple redirect rule in your `.htaccess` file that redirects all URL's with `index.php` to your new (and better) URL's?

Comment: It's kind of a long story, i know I can use 301 redirects...but to be simpler, at this moment there are 2 website versions online (old domain and new domain on WordPress) , I'm pointing cross-domain canonical from old to the new domain...and i need the HTTP header as `200 OK`